# Eclipse, JDT: Find a file on the classpath knowing its fully qualified name

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

Given the name `ch/mollusca/sample/snippet.xml`, is there an easy way to get a hold of this file in JDT code, when it is located in the projects classpath either as a source file or inside a JAR?

The file may also be inside another project, that is referenced by the one, where I'm trying to get a hold of the actual file behind the name.

This is specific to Java projects, so it's possible to get a hold of the IJavaProject if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you want, but it's the best I can do (and since your question already has 2 days, I might has well throw you this):

[Eclipse Corner Articles: Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html)

[Eclipse JDT - Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html)

These two great articles will point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```java
IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
if ( activeEditor != null ) {
    IResource activeEditorResource = (IResource)activeEditor.getEditorInput().getAdapter( IResource.class );
    if ( activeEditorResource != null && activeEditorResource.getFullPath() != null ) {
        String activeFileName = activeEditorResource.getFullPath().toOSString();
        //...do something with the active file
    }
}
```